# Двумерный массив Js

Tags: javascript, массивы

Матрица М состоит из 6 строк, 8 столбцов. Выяснить, сколько элементов в каждой строке превышают среднее арифметическое значение, определенное для этой строки. Из найденных величин составить массив Р.

P.s сделал переменную, она задумывалась как среднее арифметическое строки, но не вышло

```
var theArithmeticMean = 0;

    function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }

    function CreateAnArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
        var arr = new Array();
        for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
            arr[i] = new Array();

            for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
                arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 10); 
                theArithmeticMean += parseInt(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    var myMatrix = CreateAnArray(8,6); //Вызов функции для создания массива
    console.log(myMatrix);
    console.log(theArithmeticMean);
```

Comment: Почему не вышло? Что не получается? Судя по коду в матрице 8 строк и 6 колонок, а не наоборот.

Comment: Ну, смотрите, не получается подсчитать сумму каждой строки для дальнейших действий. В приведенном коде он считает сумму всех элементов массива

Comment: Ну заведите массив для сумм строк.

Comment: Тогда каким образом мне обращаться к конкретно строке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/**
 * Функция для генерации случайного целого числа
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

/**
 * Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
 */
function CreateAnArray(rows, columns) {
 var arr = new Array();
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array();

  for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
   arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 10);
  }
 }
 return arr;
}

/**
 * Возвращает массив с количеством элементов превышающих средние по срокам в матрице
 */
function getCountsAverages(matrix) {

 var result = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

  // считаем среднее для строки
  var sum = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
   sum += matrix[i][j];
  }
  var average = sum / matrix[i].length;

  // считаем количество элементов превысивших среднее по строке
  result[i] = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
   if (matrix[i][j] > average) {
    result[i] += 1;
   }
  }

  // для проверки выводим в консоль
  console.log("строка " + (i + 1) + ": " + matrix[i], "среднее: " + average, "количество: " + result[i]);
 }
 return result;
}

var myMatrix = CreateAnArray(8, 6); // Вызов функции для создания массива

//console.log(myMatrix);

var P = getCountsAverages(myMatrix);

console.log("результат: " + P);
```